How can I copy a clip in Ableton Live so that we need to make a change to the clip, all copies of the clip are changed accordingly?
How can I copy a clip in Ableton Live so that we need to make a change to the clip, all copies of the clip are changed accordingly? E.g., in Cubase one can do so via ghost copies.

This is a no-brainer feature and it has been asked for since forever. I've been using Ableton since 2008 and shadow copies was already a common feature request.

Sorry, this is not a current feature in Ableton Live.
If you have Max for Live, there is at least one M4L device that can add this functionality: Alias Clips.

Using repeating loops is kind of a little bit like shadow copies. Looped repeats change automatically when you change the main loop.
